# Scrolling div inside a div with max-height set

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div that scrolls its content inside of a div with has `height: auto and max-height:(heightpx);` set on it. I noticed that if I set height to be a value and remove the max-height it works.

```
<div style="height:auto; max-height:200px; background:red;">
<div class="fill">
    <div class="fill">
        <div class="fill">
            <div class="scrolly" style="height: calc(100% - 45px)">
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.scrolly {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.fill {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szze6a66/

Comment: It would be helpful if you would put the code inline by using the editor rather than posting a link to a jsfiddle.  You can add code by pasting it into the comment box, hilighting it, and then clicking the "code" (looks like {}) button.

Answer (score 6):

you just need `overflow-y: auto` and set the height.

```
.scrolly {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure he wants to have fluid 100% height, not fixed 200px

Answer (score 2):

overflow-y: auto

```
<div style=" max-height:200px; background:red; overflow-y:auto">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djktzyec/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You've applied the scrolly class to the wrong div. Remove it from the div it's on in your example and add it to the parent div.

Comment: Thank you, however in this situation I am trying to get the child div its self to scroll not the parent. For example if I add a textbox as the first element in the parent, I was wondering if there is still a way to get the div with the "hellos" to scoll
`<div class="scrolly" style="height:auto; max-height:200px; background:red;">
    <input/>
    <div class="fill">
        <div class="fill">
            <div class="fill">
                <div class="scrolly" style="height: 100%">
                    <div>hello</div>
                   '`
http://jsfiddle.net/szze6a66/2/

Comment: I don't know that you can unless you apply a fixed height to the scrolling child div.

Answer (score -1):

As the main `div` has `max-height:200px` then you can set the tag with `.scrolly` class to `max-height: 200px` then it will scroll instead of overflowing the container.

```css
.scrolly {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.fill {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:auto; max-height:200px; background:red;">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="fill">
      <div class="fill">
        <div class="scrolly">
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <div>hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure he wants to have fluid 100% height, not fixed 200px